# Spawned phantomjs process hanging

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to create a node server that spawns phantomjs processes to create screenshots. The grab.js script works fine when executed and I've confirmed that it writes to stdout. Problem is the node code that spawns the process simply hangs. I've confirmed that phantomjs is in the path. Anyone know what might be happening here or how I might troubleshoot this?

Here's the phantomjs code (grab.js) that renders the page and writes the data to stdout:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
  system = require('system'),
  fs = require('fs');

var url = system.args[1] || 'google.com';

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1024,
  height: 1200
};

page.open(url, function() {
  var b64 = page.renderBase64('png');
  fs.write('/dev/stdout', b64, 'w');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

And here's the node code that spawns the phantom progress and prints the result (hangs):

```
var http = require('http'),
  exec = require('child_process').exec,
  fs = require('fs');

exec('phantomjs grab.js google.com', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(error, stdout, stderr);
});
```

Comment: Seems like there's a problem writing to stdout. Which is weird because the script is running as root. "Unable to open file '/dev/stdout'"

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phantomjs/2rFv57riMR4 should resolve your problem.you need phantom-proxy or others which build on phantom-proxy

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with exec and then switched to using spawn instead and it worked.
According to this [article](http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html) , *Use spawn when you want the child process to return huge binary data to Node, use exec when you want the child process to return simple status messages.*
hth

Comment: I actually tried both if I remember correctly. I used `exec` for the example since it's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, in my case it was not in nodejs, but in phantomjs (v2.1).

[It's known problem](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14529) when phantom`s open method hangs.

Also, found [second link](http://qaru.site/questions/12473815/how-to-exit-phantom-if-it-hangs-on-pageopen-with-example) (I guess same person wrote) in which author points that requestAnimationFrame is not working well with tweenJs, which causes freezing. PhantomJS returns unixtimestamp but tweenjs expects it to be DOMHighResTimeStamp, and so on...

Trick is to inject request-animation-frame.js (which is also provided in that article)